# Julia - Equivalent of tf.layers.dense

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, julia

Does a function exist in Julia to create a dense layer ?

An equivalent to the function [tf.layers.dense](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/dense)  in Python ?

```
tf.layers.dense(
    inputs,
    units,
    activation=None,
    use_bias=True,
    kernel_initializer=None,
    bias_initializer=tf.zeros_initializer(),
    kernel_regularizer=None,
    bias_regularizer=None,
    activity_regularizer=None,
    kernel_constraint=None,
    bias_constraint=None,
    trainable=True,
    name=None,
    reuse=None
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No,
The [Layers module](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/contrib.layers) in python tensorflow, is a **contrib** module.
That means (amongst other things), 
it will not normally be available in TensorFlow binding for any language other than Python (because it doesn't correspond to an operation in `libtensorflow.so`.)

However, Dense layers are trivially implementable from first principles in tensorflow.

A simple dense layer is:

```
using TensorFlow
@tf begin
    X=placeholder(Float32; shape=[-1, 10])

    W = get_variable((10, 100), Float32)
    b = get_variable(100, Float32)

    Y = nn.relu(X*W + b)
end
```

So from there you could build your own Dense function
To get you started, something like

```
using TensorFlow: get_shape

function dense(inputs::Tensor, units::Int, activation=identity, name=randstring())
    in_dims = get_shape(inputs, 2)

    W = get_variable("W_$name", (in_dims, units), Float32)
    b = get_variable("b_$name", units, Float32)

    activation(inputs*W + b)
end
```

That could readily be extended to do whatever you needed.

Comment: Thank you for this useful function.  There is a problem with the get_variable: `ERROR: MethodError: no method matching get_variable(::Tuple{Int64,Int64}, ::Type{Float32})`   Any idea to fix that ?

Comment: Fixed, forgot to name the variables. I'm sure you can devise a better name than randomly generating on, but for demos sake...

Comment: Thank you. Just to be sure, H is the input ?

Comment: Oops fixed, this is what I get for quickly putting out an answer at the end of the day without testing it. `inputs` is the input.

Answer (score 0):

Look at `Dense` in [Flux.jl](https://github.com/FluxML/Flux.jl#features). See the README and docs for details, but it acts very similarly.

Flux.jl is not TensorFlow, but is a newer pure julia neural network library.